# Automatorで保存するファイル名を指定するには

Tags: macos, automator

automatorで以下の処理をする場合に,Excelブックの名前が「名称未設定」と固定なので
任意の名前の入力を求めるようにしたいです。

```
１．Finde項目の選択ダイアログを出す
２．エクセルブックにcsvファイルをインポート
３．名前の入力をダイアログで要求
４．名前をつけてexcelブックを保存
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: スクリーンショットに写っている「名前をつけてブックを保存する」の「ファイル名：」のテキストを変更すれば良いと思ったのですが、そういうことではないのですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ファイル名の部分には変数を使うことができます。

[image: スクリーンショット]